# Store ejabberd cluster log at same location

Tags: logging, erlang, ejabberd

I have setup ejabberd cluster with two machine. I am doing log analysis on ejabberd server log. But, both the machine store ejabberd logs in their local  directory. **So, the problem is that How to store two machines logs in ejabberd cluster at the same directory.**

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd can only store log for each node locally. You need to use an external tool/script to gather and merge the log for analysis. You could have a script for example that copy logs on a local machine, in the same directory with proper name for node, parse them and merge them.

Other approach is to use a tool like [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/) to centralize the logs on a remote service (This is a SaaS platform, so there is a cost). You could integrate Rollbar Erlang library (like https://github.com/omarkj/erollbar) to report error to Rollbar instead of standard logger.

Another approach is to integrate a lager backend for your service of choice into ejabberd. For example, you can add Lager Graylog backend to centralize logs on a Graylog server: https://github.com/avalente/lager_graylog_backend

Finally, you could write your own custom log handler for Lager and use it with ejabberd to report error to your own custom service.

Comment: When Will be ejabberd launch persistant room feature? Ejabberd 16.02 has been launched. But, Does it support this feature.